# OpenAM not forwarding SAMLResponse

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, openam

When I hit the SP initiated URL, it gets authenticated and gets redirected to my application page. But I don't get the SAMLResponse in the application's request object.
Whereas, SAMLResponse is available in SP i.e, OpenAM's request(Attached are the network logs of chrome).

I suspect the J2EE policy agent configuration in Tomcat7 should be the issue. But wondering how to verify whether it is correct or not. Followed the procedure from [Forgerock](http://openam.forgerock.org/openam-documentation/openam-doc-source/doc/jee-users-guide/#chap-apache-tomcat).

Any help is highly appreciable! Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be mixing up the different technologies: the agents are NOT SAML based, and any kind of assertion received by OpenAM will not be exposed to agent protected applications.

Comment: Agreed. By default OpenAM doesn't expose. But, is there a way to forward/share the response from OpenAM to my application?

Comment: I don't think there is anything out of the box that would allow you to do that. If you really need a SAML assertion probably you actually want to use the STS feature instead.